# How to borrow a method from a different object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Inheritance, and I was just trying to inherit a method from a different object in JavaScript, but when I run the code it gives an `undefined function` error.

Can anyone please help me how do I inherit the method from a different object?

Below is the JS Snippet:

```
var palestrina = {
    work: "MTS",
    describe: function() {
        return this.work;
    }
};

var pale = {
    work: "STMS"
    describe: palestrina.describe.bind(this)
};

console.log(palestrina.describe());
console.log(pale.describe());
```

[JSfiddle for the same](http://jsfiddle.net/909ffnco/)

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` is determined by *how the current function was called*.

Since you aren't in a function, it will be `window`.

There is no way to get a reference to `pale` that you can pass to `bind` until after you've created the object.

However, you don't need to. Since the value of `this` depends on how the function is called (as opposed to how it was constructed), you can just copy the reference to the function:

```
var pale = {
    work: "STMS",
    describe: palestrina.describe
};
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, can you please change in the jsfiddle and leme know.

Comment: @Andy : Can you tell me what is the difference between what quentin suggested and palestrina.describe.call(pale)

Comment: @SharathBangera–the outcome is the same. Both methods set *this* within the function to *pale*. See Quentin's very first sentence (which should go on to say "*or by the use of bind*").

Comment: @SharathBangera — As mentioned in the third paragraph of the answer, `pale` is undefined at the time you are trying to access it.